# subdomain | ASP.NET | Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, server-error

I am having problems using a subdomain and ASP.NET, I guess it must be something  very simple I just do not know what.

If you would like to go right to the point just jump to no. 7 below...

TVM, RConte

1. My hosted domain:

   ### Hosted Service Domains:   MYDOMAIN.net
2. Added a subdomain: (rfpesquisa)
   Sub Domains
   Sub Domain   Remove

   ### rfpesquisa  Remove                                    [THIS ONE]
3. Added a "A" record in DNS                       [see below]

Hosted DNS MYDOMAIN.net

$ORIGIN MYDOMAIN.net.
$TTL 86400
.....etc
rfpesquisa    86400    IN A     174.36.13.167    [THIS ONE, COPIED FROM...]

### www           86400    IN A     174.36.13.167    [...THIS ONE]

TESTS MADE:

1. Acessed main page (not the subdomain)  as usual:
   (http://)www.MYDOMAIN.net/AcessaPesquisa.aspx

### works fine !

1. Added a "kkk" so as to make for a wrong url:
   (http://)www.MYDOMAINkkk.net/AcessaPesquisa.aspx

gives:

### "Could not locate remote server"           [as expected]

1. Tried a non-existing subdomain, XXXXXX
   (http://)XXXXXX.MYDOMAIN.net/AcessaPesquisa.aspx

gives: 
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

### [witch means to me that the server was found but the subdomain per se was not found]

1. Tried what I am look for dooing: (used the subdomain rfpesquisa)
   (http://)rfpesquisa.MYDOMAIN.net/AcessaPesquisa.aspx
   Message I got: 
   Server Error in '/' Application.
   The resource cannot be found. 
   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

   ### Requested URL: /AcessaPesquisa.aspx

given that ASP.NET Message, it  means to me that

--the subdomain WAS found, 
the request was given to ASP.NET dll, only
it is NOT pointing to the same place as the domain, otherwise 
the results for this try and no.4, the rigth one, would be the same.

## file "AcessaPesquisa.aspx" is NOT in the target directory.

Please, how do I point the subdomain to the right place ?

Thank you very much,
Ricardo Conte

Answer (score 0):

I guess 
(1) you are using pan-domain service (one of DNS registry, redirecting requests to all sub-domains *.mydomain.net to the same server) 
AND
(2) in your IIS configuration of this server, you've bound the website and the host name "www.mydomain.net" together.

Comment: Folks, as I said, it is very simple, only I had never done that: my hosting provider creates a sub-directory in my domain, and this is the place pointed to when acessed, not the root directory !!!

Simple mistakes or simple facts not known sometimes lead to some time lost, in this case "only" 3 days... (thak you percyboy, for your answer...)

Regards, R Conte